# Buildozer For Python3 Unknown File Type ".pxi" error

Tags: android, python-3.x, apk, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to compile a simple kivy app into an apk but I keep getting this error: error: unknown file type '.pxi' (from 'jnius/jni.pxi'). I believe the issue is cython but I don't know how to fix it. I've tried using different cython versions (0.25, 0.26 and 0.27).

Full log - https://jpst.it/17EwW

Comment: Kivy version 1.10.0 is compatible with Cython version 0.25.2.

Comment: 0.26 worked just fine too alongside with the suggestion of @inclement

Comment: Previously, I have used Cython 0.26 until I encountered BCMDisplayException. After I down graded it to Cython 0.25.2 or 0.25, it solved the problem. The Cython dependencies is mentioned at Kivy.org website, https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-11-10-or-newer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discussed this error with another user, but never worked out quite what the issue is. However, their problems were eventually resolved by making sure Kivy and python-for-android were up to date. In this case, you could try changing `kivy` to `kivy==master` in the buildozer.spec requirements line, then cleaning everything and trying the build again.

It may also help to make sure your cython version is 0.25 or 0.26, although I think any recent version should work with Kivy master.

Comment: I used pip3 install cython==0.26 and added kivy==master to the spec file and everything worked just perfectly! Thank you so much!